# Laravel Policy works for view but not viewAny

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-7

My policy for an API controller seems to be working fine for view, but returns 'This action is unauthorized.' for viewAll, both while sending an admin api token.  Using Laravel 7 with Spatie Roles/Permissions.  AppBaseController extends Illuminate\Routing\Controller. I've tried it without the middleware, just to be sure.  Tried commenting out the 'before' function, to make sure it's not conflicting.  Double-checked I'm sending Answer::class with the viewAny call. Confirmed the model 'can' method also returns false on viewAny.  Tried it with and without optional User parameter in viewAny.  Read and re-read the documentation, and every similar issue on here I could find.  Can't seem to work out the issue.  Not even sure how to trace what Laravel is doing to get that response.

routes/api.php

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| API Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register API routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| is assigned the "api" middleware group. Enjoy building your API!
|
*/

//logged in
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth:api', 'verified']], function () {
    Route::get('answers', 'AnswerAPIController@index')->name('answers.index');
    Route::post('answers/{id}', 'AnswerAPIController@store')->name('answers.store');
    Route::get('answers/{id}', 'AnswerAPIController@show')->name('answers.show');
    Route::put('answers/{id}', 'AnswerAPIController@update')->name('answers.update');
    Route::delete('answers/{id}', 'AnswerAPIController@destroy')->name('answers.destroy');
});
```

AnswerPolicy.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Policies;

use App\Models\Answer;
use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Auth\Access\HandlesAuthorization;

class AnswerPolicy
{
    use HandlesAuthorization;
    
    /**
     * Perform pre-authorization checks.
     *
     * @param  \App\Models\User  $user
     * @param  string  $ability
     * @return void|bool
     */
    public function before(User $user, $ability)
    {
        if ($user->hasRole('admin')) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Determine whether the user can view any answers.
     *
     * @param  \App\Models\User  $user
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function viewAny(User $user)
    {
        return true;
        //
        // if ($user !== null) {
        //     return true;
        // }
    }

    /**
     * Determine whether the user can view the answer.
     *
     * @param  \App\Models\User|null $user
     * @param  \App\Models\Answer  $answer
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function view(?User $user, Answer $answer)
    {
        
        return true;
        // if ($answer->published) {
        //     return true;
        // }

        // visitors cannot view unpublished items
        // if ($user === null) {
        //     return false;
        // }

        // // admin overrides published status
        // if ($user->can('view answers')) {
        //     return true;
        // }
    }

    /**
     * Determine whether the user can create answers.
     *
     * @param  \App\Models\User  $user
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function create(User $user)
    {
        return true;
        // if ($user->can('create answers')) {
        //     return true;
        // }
    }

    /**
     * Determine whether the user can update the answer.
     *
     * @param  \App\Models\User  $user
     * @param  \App\Models\Answer  $answer
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function update(User $user, Answer $answer)
    {
        return true;
        // if ($user->can('edit answers')) {
        //     return true;
        // }
    }

    /**
     * Determine whether the user can delete the answer.
     *
     * @param  \App\Models\User  $user
     * @param  \App\Models\Answer  $answer
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function delete(User $user, Answer $answer)
    {
        return true;
        // if ($user->can('delete answers')) {
        //     return $user->id == $answer->user_id;
        // }
    }

    /**
     * Determine whether the user can restore the answer.
     *
     * @param  \App\Models\User  $user
     * @param  \App\Models\Answer  $answer
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function restore(User $user, Answer $answer)
    {
        return true;
        //
    }

    /**
     * Determine whether the user can permanently delete the answer.
     *
     * @param  \App\Models\User  $user
     * @param  \App\Models\Answer  $answer
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function forceDelete(User $user, Answer $answer)
    {
        return true;
        //
    }
}
```

AnswerAPIController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\API;

use Auth;
use Log;
use Throwable;
use App\Http\Controllers\AppBaseController;
use App\Http\Requests\API\CreateAnswerAPIRequest;
use App\Http\Requests\API\UpdateAnswerAPIRequest;
use App\Repositories\AnswerRepository;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\Access\AuthorizesRequests;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Response;
use Spatie\Permission\Models\Role;
use Spatie\Permission\Models\Permission;

/**
 * Class AnswerController
 * @package App\Http\Controllers\API
 */

class AnswerAPIController extends AppBaseController
{
    
    use AuthorizesRequests;
    
    /** @var  AnswerRepository */
    private $answerRepository;

    public function __construct(AnswerRepository $answerRepo)
    {
        $this->answerRepository = $answerRepo;
    }

    /**
     * @param Request $request
     * @return Response
     */
    public function index(Request $request)
    {
        
        try {

            $this->authorize('viewAny', Answer::class);

            $answers = $this->answerRepository->all(
                $request->has('search') ? $request->get('search') : [],
                $request->has('skip') && $request->has('limit') ? $request->get('skip') : null,
                $request->has('limit') ? $request->get('limit') : null,
                $request->has('columns') ? $request->get('columns') : ['*'],
                $request->has('with') ? $request->get('with') : null,
                $request->has('sort') ? $request->get('sort') : 'id',
                $request->has('direction') ? $request->get('direction') : 'asc'
            );

            return $this->sendResponse($answers->toArray(), 'Answers retrieved successfully.');
        } catch (Throwable $e) {
            $trace = $e->getTrace()[array_search(__FILE__, array_column($e->getTrace(), 'file'))];
            Log::error($e->getMessage() . " (" . $trace['file'] . ":" . $trace['line'] . ")\r\n" . '[stacktrace]' . "\r\n" . $e->getTraceAsString());
            return $this->sendError($e->getMessage(), $request->all());
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param int $id
     * @return Response
     */
    public function show($id, Request $request)
    {
        try {
            /** @var Answer $answer */
            $answer = $this->answerRepository->find(
                $id,
                $request->has('columns') ? $request->get('columns') : ['*'],
                $request->has('with') ? $request->get('with') : null
            );
        
            $this->authorize('view', $answer);

            if (empty($answer)) {
                return $this->sendError('Answer (' . $id . ') not found.');
            }

            return $this->sendResponse($answer->toArray(), 'Answer retrieved successfully.');
        } catch (Throwable $e) {
            $trace = $e->getTrace()[array_search(__FILE__, array_column($e->getTrace(), 'file'))];
            Log::error($e->getMessage() . " (" . $trace['file'] . ":" . $trace['line'] . ")\r\n" . '[stacktrace]' . "\r\n" . $e->getTraceAsString());
            return $this->sendError($e->getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

request URL (index)

```
https://evenpulse.test/api/answers?api_token=****
```

response

```
{
  "success": false,
  "message": "This action is unauthorized.",
  "data": {
    "api_token": "****"
  }
}
```

request URL (view)

```
https://evenpulse.test/api/answers/1?api_token=****
```

response

```
{
  "success": true,
  "data": {
    "id": 1,
    "question_id": 1,
    "order": 1,
    "text": "asdf",
    "is_correct": false
  },
  "message": "Answer retrieved successfully."
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In a classic case of 'asking often illuminates the problem', I figured it out 30 seconds later, after two days of struggles.

In the 'viewAny' authorize method I had put in the Answer::class bit, but nowhere in the controller did I define what 'Answer' is.  I fixed it by adding

```
use App\Models\Answer;
```

to the top of the controller.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging :) Glad you got it working though!